# How to send multiple sets of data through multipeer connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, encode, multipeer-connectivity

I want to be able to use

```
appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData
```

however on the receiving end there is no way of getting the same variables, for instance to receive any bit of data as far as I know you would have to write something like this

```
func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceiveData: \(data.length) bytes")
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}
```

Does anybody else know of any way in multipeer connectivity to send and receive more than one set of Data, as I want to be able to constantly be streaming a song duration but at the beginning of a song I need to send out the name of the song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a dictionary by converting it to NSData as follows:

```
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)
```

On the receiving side it would look something like this:

```
override func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    let dictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    NSLog("Peer \(peerID) has sent message \(dictionary)")
    .....
}
```

This would allow you to send the initial data. Then you would use

```
- startStreamWithName:toPeer:error:
```

to start sending the stream. This creates a connected byte stream (NSOutputStream) that you can use to send data to the specified peer.

Comment: Are there any blog posts that better explain how to use streams in multipeer connectivity as the framework reference does not go into that much detail and I don't quite understand what I would put inside of my stream function to send across lets say for instance an integer on a regular basis